# Generate XSD from SQL Server database in order to import XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, import, xsd, bulkinsert

Is there a tool to generate an XSD schema from SQL Server database ?

This XSD would be used for importing XML data into database with `BULK INSERT` or `bcp`